# Pyzmq - Send multiple messages without blocking

Tags: python, pyzmq

I want to send multiple messages from one socket to another and I encountered this problem.

**client.py**

```
context = Context()

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    out_socket = context.socket(REQ)
    out_socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % "5000")
    message_content = ("hello", 1)
    pickled_message = dumps(message_content)
    out_socket.send(pickled_message, flags=NOBLOCK)
```

**Server.py**

```
context = Context()
in_socket = context.socket(REP)
in_socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % "5000")

poller = Poller()
poller.register(in_socket, POLLIN)

while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll())
    print(socks)

    if socks.get(in_socket) == POLLIN:
        pickled_received_message = in_socket.recv(flags=NOBLOCK)
        received_message, sender_entity_id_e = loads(pickled_received_message)
        print(received_message, sender_entity_id_e)
```

**Output of client.py**

**client.py** outputs numbers printed from 0 to 9. This made me thought that messages were sent and it worked. Then I took closer look at **server.py** and realized that although for cycle ran 10 times only one message was send.

What I want to realize is to send multiple messages from client to server without blocking. Any ideas how to achieve this? I already tried several solutions without success. I think this should work but I am not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

### ZeroMQ infrastructure works in a documented manner

If it says, that an asynchronous service does not deliver a message in the very moment a non-blocking call to a **`.send( something, flags = zmq.DONTWAIT )`** method has returned, it indeed means that the ZeroMQ service infrastructure took the ownership of the message payload ( the **`something`**, in this example ), but nothing less and nothing more.

Next, the same principle works at **`.bind()/.connect()`** methods, that start to build a next ZeroMQ infrastructure AccessPoint, be it locally ( for a `.bind()`-case ), or remotely ( in case a `.connect()`-method was asked to start to do some low-level, transport-class-specific series of steps and remedies ), some of which may, after some remarkable time ( just benchmark it, how long does it take to reach an RTO-state, in **`[us]`**, since an infrastructure setup was asked to start to be built to have a rough estimate, how long it may take before going into a production-ready state... )

```
context = Context()
"""        
for        i in range( 10 ):
    print( i ) # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------- NEVER THIS WAY [us].....
    out_socket = context.socket( REQ )
    out_socket.connect( "tcp://localhost:%s" % "5000" )
    message_content = ( "hello", 1 )
    pass;            pickled_message = dumps( message_content )
    out_socket.send( pickled_message, flags = NOBLOCK )
"""
#-------------------------------------------------ZMQ-# <INSTANTIATION>
out_socket = context.socket( zmq.REQ )                # .SET AN INSTANCE
out_socket.setsockopt(       zmq.LINGER, 0 )          # .SET ALWAYS
out_socket.setsockopt(       zmq.SNDHWM, ... )        # .SET AS NEEDED
out_socket.setsockopt(       zmq.AFFINITY, ... )      # .SET AS NEEDED
out_socket.setsockopt(       zmq.<_*-attributes_>,...)# .SET AS NEEDED
#-------------------------------------------------ZMQ-# <INFRASTRUCTURE>
out_socket.connect( "tcp://localhost:%s" % "5000" )   # .CONNECT()-async call

for        i in range( 100 ):                         # py2.7: xrange( 100 ):
    print( i )
    # -------------------------------------------------------
    #                  pass;                   message_content = ( "hello", 1 )
    #                  pickled_message = dumps(message_content)
    # out_socket.send( pickled_message, flags = NOBLOCK )
    #-------------------------------------------------------- PYTHON-SIDE COSTS
    out_socket.send(                     dumps( ( "hello", i ) ), zmq.DONTWAIT )
print( "finished the for()-loops" )
#-------------------------------------------------ZMQ-# <GRACEFUL TERMINATION>
out_socket.close()
context.term()
```